# UINavigationController blocks UITabBar with SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

Working on an app that has a slide-out menu and a tabbar, similar to facebook. My problem is that the SWRevealController works perfectly and everything transitions fine. However, the tab bar buttons are hidden after a view is changed. Take a look at my storyboard hierarchy:  https://drive.google.com/a/stolaf.edu/file/d/0BxPvzAFa0lPjclp4c01Jb1RsQ1U/view

Here is the segue push code that pushes each view.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{
    // Set the title of navigation bar by using the menu items
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    // Set the photo if it navigates to the PhotoView


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tab"]) {


        Tabbar *photoController = (Tabbar*)segue.destinationViewController;

        photoController.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
    }




    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {


        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {


            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];

            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };

    }

}
```

Not entirely sure but I think the navigation controller that is created in the segue is the one that is being added over the tab bar hence hiding all tab bar buttons completely. Any thoughts?

Comment: y u take this , simple u can take at **didselectrowatindexpath**

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem like you and I have written this code. We have to get first taBarController and then it's navigation controller.

```
if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
    SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

    swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

        UITabBarController *tab = (UITabBarController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        int index = tab.selectedIndex;
        UINavigationController *nav = [tab viewControllers][index];
//        [nav pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
        [nav setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated:NO];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
    };

}
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Or are you saying that you have the same question?

Comment: best answer Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue..
  Doing a simple

```
self.view.tabbarcontroller.tabbar.hidden=NO;
```

did the trick for me,

add this in the view did load method of the particular viewcontrollor, it will run fine.

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried that but it hides the tab bar all together. I want it so that the nav controller does not block the tab bar.